# Add punctuation to tokenized sentence if missing in HuggingFace

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface-tokenizers

Given some raw sentence data, such as a tweet, I am tokenizing it with [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/), which is working well to do some data cleaning like the following:

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vinai/bertweet-base", normalization=True)

line = "DHEC confirms https://postandcourier.com/health/covid19/sc-has-first-two-presumptive-cases-of-coronavirus-dhec-confirms/article_bddfe4ae-5fd3-11ea-9ce4-5f495366cee6.html?utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter&utm_campaign=user-share… via @postandcourier "
ids = tokenizer.encode(line)
tokenizer.decode(ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

The line `ids = tokenizer.encode(line)` gives me

```
[0, 429, 6814, 499, 12952, 10, 28, 156, 5, 1713, 2]
```

Which is good, and decoding it with `tokenizer.decode(ids, skip_special_tokens=True)` returns

```
'DHEC confirms HTTPURL... via @USER :crying_face:'
```

Which is perfect so far.

How do I detect if the last character is sentence-ending punctuation like `? ! .`, and add a period (`.`) to the sentence if it is missing? Meaning, that the following would returned as this:

```
 'DHEC confirms HTTPURL... via @USER :crying_face:.'
```

Instead of this:

```
 'DHEC confirms HTTPURL... via @USER :crying_face:'
```

And if there already was sentence-ending punctuation, it would not be modified.